# JavaFX Virtual Table View

Tags: java, javafx, swt, tableview, lazy-loading

I am comparatively very new to Javafx & I am using the javafx TableView to display my data in a new javafx application. I come from eclipse RCP ( SWT/JFace) background and would like to implement the lazy loading of table items in the javafx table view. ( similar to SWT.VIRTUAL & listening on SWT.Setdata in a SWT terminology).

My requirement is to basically get data from the database in chunks of 100 and appending to the existing items in the table on scroll down .

Is this a valid requirement from a Javafx perspective ? If not, are there any other ways to achieve the lazy loading.

Many Thanks.

Regards,
Santhosh

Comment: Retrieving items on scroll will be tricky, if not impossible. Note that in a JavaFX `TableView`, UI nodes are only created for the *visible* data anyway; in (almost?) all cases you can readily store the data associated with a table far bigger than any user will want to deal with. So it may be best just to load all the data and let the JavaFX mechanism for "lazy display" do the work for you. A long while ago I [created a demo](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2549856) that downloaded 2 million rows into a table, the performance was just fine (the file it downloads no longer exists, though).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @James_D.  will try that out . But we are calling a webservice to fetch the data and I am not sure whether they would fire a query without setting the rowcount.  ( In this case, select * from xyz ) . So, any alternative you can think for getting data in batches ?.

Comment: I simply wouldn't; I'd get it all in one shot. You can retrieve it in a background thread and either set it to the table when it's all downloaded, or add it progressively in chunks to the table's data using `Platform.runLater(...)` calls. If you really want to get it in batches, your web service will need to support that; you could perhaps use a [`Pagination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html) so the user can page through it. At this point it's not really clear what functionality you are trying to implement though...